# Groovy NumberMath defaults to IntegerMath for unkown Number types

Tags: groovy, spock

We have a custom type called "Decimal" which extends java.lang.Number

We are using Groovy/Spock for some unit/acceptance tests.

We noticed some mysterious behaviour in our asserts.

In the following code, myDecimal's true value is 9.91

```
assert myDecimal == new Decimal(“9.91”)   // succeed. 
assert myDecimal == new Decimal(“9.02”)   // succeed. What??
assert myDecimal == new Decimal(“8.99”)   // fail.
```

One of our developers found some code in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.NumberMath.java [groovy-all-2.2.1]

```
public static NumberMath getMath(Number left, Number right) {
    if (isFloatingPoint(left) || isFloatingPoint(right)) {
        return FloatingPointMath.INSTANCE;
    }
    if (isBigDecimal(left) || isBigDecimal(right)) {
        return BigDecimalMath.INSTANCE;
    }
    if (isBigInteger(left) || isBigInteger(right)) {
        return BigIntegerMath.INSTANCE;
    }
    if (isLong(left) || isLong(right)){
        return LongMath.INSTANCE;
    }
    return IntegerMath.INSTANCE;
}
```

Seeing this method it's obvious that our custom Decimal class will be assigned an IntegerMath.  Which will cause "broken" assertions when asserting non-whole numbers.

Does anyone know of a way around this?  e.g. is there some way of providing a custom factory of NumberMath objects?

Any help would be greatly apprecated.

Comment: Is your `MyDecimal` class in Groovy?  Could you use a delegate with custom equality rather than extending Number?

Comment: For what purposes do you need your own decimal number? BigDecimal should provide everything you need.

Comment: tim_yates, No sorry, our "MyDecimal" is in Java not groovy.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of solving this:
 1. If one of the available Math instances (say, BigDecimalMath) can compare your numbers properly, then change the base class of your Decimal accordingly
 2. Otherwise, try and change the getMath method in NumberMath's metaclass. It's dirty, and I'm not even sure whether at all possible to change Groovy itself using the Metaclass. That said, I feel like checking this out in a spare moment...